# Why are sr25519 signatures non-deterministic?

Tags: cryptography, sr25519

According to the [polkadot.js docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/keyring/start/sign-verify/#using-known-pairs), both `ed25519` and `ecdsa` signatures are deterministic (given the message and private key, it always produces the same signature). However `sr25519` is not.

I understand a nonce value is usually required to sign a message. It's the source of the randomness of the signature. We can use the RFC6979 trick in `ecdsa` to generate deterministic nonce, but why cannot we use the same trick in `sr25519`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple sr25519 signature remains secure even with actively malicious system randomness, and you can pass in your own `RngCore` to have deterministic test vectors, but..

In future, schnorrkel shall support protocols like (threshold) multi-signatures which cannot be derandomized by any mechanism.  I decided to rip the band-aid off and make all sr25519 signatures non-deterministic to prevent anyone depending upon determinism elsewhere.

In the code, we inherit non-determinism from merlin, which made this choice for exactly the same reasons.

In blockchains, we distinguish between on-chain (runtime) and off-chain (host) code, but only off-chain code supports secrets and system randomness.  It's good we break a signer used in the runtime.  There is no reasons off-chain workers cannot have system randomness and secrets, but not sure the current status.

Comment: Thanks. Very useful answer!

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more why Sr25119 is non-deterministic? Maybe i have been using an incorrect definition for deterministic. I can produce a multisig out of some Sr25519 addresses off-chain. Is that part deterministic? But the signing part is non-determinsitic, perhaps now i see the distinction.

Comment: An on-chain multi-sig does not care, if that's your question.  Afaik we've no wallets with support off-chain cryptographic multi-sigs.  We've some code in schnorrkel for this, but it needs to be replaced since I wrote it before we'd proved https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1245 and thus