# Why does Grandpa not use sr25519?

Tags: consensus, grandpa, sr25519, ed25519

I note that Grandpa uses ed25519 keys rather than the substrate standard of sr25519.

Is it because sr25519 signatures are non-deterministic? ( [Why are sr25519 signatures non-deterministic?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4857/why-are-sr25519-signatures-non-deterministic) ) or is there some other reason why ed was chosen over sr? Is there some inherrent reason why Grandpa can't work (or would be insecure) using sr25519 keys?

Comment: (I'm just curious.)

Comment: I couldn't find docs explaining this.  :P